# Returning another function when IF is TRUE

Tags: excel

I'm trying to run another function when IF returns TRUE
What I'm trying to do is only run a COUNTIF function if the cell next to it has information and if the cell is empty return nothing.
I currently have this:
`=IF(A46,"=COUNTIF(A:A,A46)"," ")`
When there is nothing in A46 the cell is blank, this is what I want, but when i input any data it returns #VALUE!
I'm not even sure if this is something that can be done.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=IF(A46<>"", COUNTIF(A:A, A46), TEXT(,))
```

Comment: Why `text(,)` rather than just `""`?

Comment: As this is a learning environment, I like to introduce alternatives. `text(,)` is a good method of producing `""` inside a quoted formula in VBA.